# In Python how to make sure item in a list be processed successfully

Tags: python, list

I try this:

```
for k in  keywords_list:
    google_add = random.choice(google_adds_list)
    url = make_up_url(google_add, k, False)
    if scrape_keyword_count(k, useragent_list, url, result_dir):
        keyword_count = scrape_keyword_count(k, useragent_list, url, result_dir)
        all_keyword_count.append(keyword_count)
        print '%s Finish. Removeing it from the list' % k
        keywords_list.remove(k)
    else:
        print "%s may run into problem, removing it from list" % google_add
        google_adds_list.remove(google_add)
        with open(google_adds, 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(google_adds_list))
```

I set up many reverse proxy server for google. the server list is google_add_list
I mean to search all the item in the list with the add i provide and get the result
If google block me, the scrape_keyword_count() will return None. then i
And I need to change to another add to do the search. but the script i wrote will skip the keyword no matter the scrape_keyword_count() success or not

I know removing an item within the for loop is dangerous i will improve this part later

Comment: What do you mean by "item i has been skipped"? do_something_with must have returned True and that is why i was removed.

Comment: According to this :[https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) The for loop just take out the item once, after i do_something_with(i) the for loop will get the next item, am I wrong?

Comment: Why remove ``i``? Seems unnecessary. Can you give a simple example how  ``do_something_with`` implements?

Comment: @shierji You can take the if-else clause as a whole code block, and in this block, ``i`` is the same variable.

Comment: I have added the actual code ...

Comment: @shierji... Can you explain "And I need to change to another add to do the search". Your else case is not doing anything with "k".

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're modifying the list while iterating over it.

Use "for i in the_list[:]" instead. This will iterate over a copy of the list, fixing your "skipping" (missed elements) issue.

Comment: Nothing wrong with removing elements from the list. Appending/In place modification may be another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
new_list = []
for i in the_list:
    if do_something_with(i):
       continue
    do_something_else(i)
    new_list.append(i)
```

If `do_something_with(i)` succeeded then continue with the next item otherwise `do_something_else(i)`.

You can't mutate a list while iterating over it. If the filtered list is needed, rather than removing elements from the old one produce a new one.

Comment: He may want to do something with the_list down the line. Otherwise why bother to remove the items?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will use each item once... Your code looks fine... But I think you may not be returning the correct value in do_something_with

Try this:

```
for i in the_list:
    value = do_something_with(i)
    print bool(value)
    if value:
        the_list.remove(i)
    <etc> <etc>
```

I think you may always be returning True from do_something_with